# Resharper в проекте asp.net core 2 добавляет View в папку Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, resharper

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [ASP.NET Core 2 - ReSharper “Create
>   Razor View” adds new view to Pages
>   folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46455652/5752652)

В проекте ASP.NET Core 2 при создании нового View в контроллере ReSharper создаёт представление в папке *Pages*, а не в папке *Views* (где я обычно храню мои *Views* ;-) )

[image: resharper create razor view]
[image: view in pages folder]

В обычном приложении asp.net mvc (не core) ReSharper создаёт view в правильной папке, проблема только с проектами Core / Core 2.

Вопросы:

- Что в решарпере отвечает за выбор, где создавать view?
- Как можно поменять это поведение, чтобы view создавались в традиционном месте?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/46455652

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что это баг в решарпере и я подозреваю, что это может быть связано с новым [Razor Pages Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio), который выпущен командой .net core 2.

Так что возможно было бы лучше создать issue в багтрекере решарпера.

Однако, я нашёл способ обхода проблемы и вы можете использовать его до тех пор пока JetBrains не выпустит исправление

1. Установите nuget пакет Jetbrains Annotations.

   ```
   Install-Package JetBrains.Annotations
   ```
2. Создайте .cs файл в корне вашего проекта asp.net - я назвал его  ResharperConfig.cs - со следующим содержимым:

   ```
   using JetBrains.Annotations;

   [assembly: AspMvcMasterLocationFormat("~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat("~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaMasterLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
   [assembly: AspMvcAreaPartialViewLocationFormat("~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
   ```
3. Пересоберите проект и перезапустите Visual Studio
4. Когда вы снова откроете решение, R# обнаружит расположение для view. Теперь вы можете создавать view из контекстного меню решарпера привычным способом.

[image: Resharper issue]

Update от переводчика.

Как ни странно, но этот баг не затронул areas: при создании из области представления создаются в правильном месте.

<s>Бага похожего в трекере нет, завёл [новый](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468642)</s>.

А нет, есть: [RSRP-465732](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465732)

Исправление бага ожидается в версии 2018.1.